# fslogger : ioctl error : Bad Address

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, ioctl, fsevents

I'm using this fslogger.c to get File System Notifications in my Mac. But it works only in Leopard & SnowLeopard, not in Lion or Mountain Lion.

http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/download/fslogger.c

when trying to clone the /dev/fsevents using ioctl it returns the error number 14(Bad Address). I have tried fixing it,i thought it could be some issues in ioctl function arguments. So i have tried modifying that, but no use at all. I couldn't get that fixed at all. Any idea how to make it work for Lion & Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Lion Onwards, the Security has been increased. So i have to open the file with a Third argument "S_IROTH". That will give access to /dev/fsevents device stream.  Hope this is helpful to someone like me.

Comment: Where exactly the error was? and how did you fix it? can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: When you try to clone the /dev/fsvents stream after getting the file descriptor, it will give the above error.

Comment: Actually I was able to compile and run but output is not right except string and what io was called. Uid, gid, permission bits do not look right because they are all same overall. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can you post the Mac OS X Version and the  output you got.